# Why Kukke Subramanya temple has a Madhwa mutt?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism, shaiva-siddhanta

This question is specific to kukke Subramanya temple present in Dakshina Kannada District of Karnataka (refer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kukke_Subramanya_Temple).

The main presiding deity is Subramanya i,e, a Shaiva deity. But the governing mutt belongs to Madhwa sampradaya i.e. Vaishnava sampradaya. Does anyone know the reason for this? Just curious to know the real history.

Also, as per temple history, Adi Shankaracharya stayed here during his digvijaya yatra and composed strotra praising the deity. So why not a Shankara mutt in this place?
Just curious to know the real history. No question of hurting any faith here.

Comment: Just for information Adi shankaracharya's aradhya devta was Shriman Narayana and Advita is a Vaishnava philosophy, which is extended to shaivism by later acharyas by using/exploiting the Panchayatan system which includes, Sauras, Ganpatas, Shaivas, Shaktas, and Vaishnavas.So if adi Shankaracharya would have established mutt there they might be vaishnava's as well, and would be later converted to Shaivas.

Comment: @Yogi Can you provide me proper references proving that AdiShankaracharya's Aaradhya Devata was Lord Vishnu?

Comment: @TheDestroyer you can read the Bramha Sutra bhasya by adi shankaracharya http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/index.htm there are many proofs there itself. To be specific you can read bhaja govindam as it was a spontaneous creation on the banks of Ganges at Kashi, While he saw an old Bramhin teaching Grammer to kids for making his living. The lyrics speak about his devotion towards shriman narayana.

Comment: I think its improper to label Adi Shankara as Vaishnava or Shaiva. He proposed advaita which is oneness or beyond all dualities

Comment: Hi if u know kannada then there is a book "kukke shri subrahmanya mattu mareyada siddhivinaya devaru" in a fight of sthanika(shaiva)brahmins and madhwas stahanikas lost kukke temple nothing else upto 1845 it was with shaivates then only they took over

Comment: Huh.Adi Shankara's Aradhya ws Nirguna Parambrahma (Pranava Omkara).He ws neither a Shaiva nor a Vaishnava.The proof is tht he rejectd bth Padhupata n Vaishnava philosophiesVedas say sivam advaitam n shankara says Shivohom.n aftr hs Digvijaya,it spreads in2 vaishnavas n pashupatas also n converted thm.Still jst 4 info...In Shiva Manasa Strotam he said thus, Matha cha Parvathy Devi,Pitha devo Maheswara,Bandhava Shiva Bakthamscha, Swadeso Bhuvana thrayam.My mother is the goddess Parvathy,My father is the Lord Shiva,My friends are the devotees of Shiva And my native place is all the three worlds.

Comment: Sriman Madvacharya visited kukke and converted shivani brahmin doing pooja i dont why he left sringeri or sringeri peeta must have later formation after  Madvacharya

Comment: Here is a comment which is specific to the deity affiliation allegations about Shankaracharya. Please refer to these documents:  1. This is about the citations from Shankara's Vishnu Sahasra Nama bhashya for Harihara abheda and Trimurti aikya:  https://adbhutam.files.wordpress.com/2022/05/eng-vsn-bh-citations-from-puranas.pdf    2. Did Shankara establish the Shanmatas: sixfold deity worship?  https://adbhutam.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/shankara-shanmata-eng.pdf   3. Vishnu of Shankara and that of Ramanuja: https://adbhutam.files.wordpress.com/2021/04/vishnu-of-shankara-and-ramanuja-1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Kukke subrahmanya temple was older than Adi shankara.. And composed him a hym  bhaje kukke lingam.. But after going on madhwacharya converted this shivalli Brahmins in to his dwaitha tradition..and constructed a mutt near temple..

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please cite authentic scriptural reference from vedas, upanishads, acharyas, tantras...etc..

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with proper sources. Pleas visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)

Answer (score 1):

An empty branch of Sringeri Mutt is still there besides samputa Narasimha mutt in kukke subramanya. ( [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subramanya,_Karnataka) )

Due to [Regulating act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulating_Act_of_1773) from East India Company temple administration was transferred from Shiva Brahmins to Madhwa brahmins [[Reference (This book written by Madhwa Brahmin)]](https://archive.org/details/Tulunadu_201602/page/n109)

For more detail about fate of Shiva Brahmins can refer this Book [Tulunadina Itihasadalli](https://ia802701.us.archive.org/6/items/TulunadinaItihasadalliSthanikaBrahmanaru/Tulunadina%20Itihasadalli%20Sthanika%20Brahmanaru.pdf)

EndNote: From past history we can see that for every 300 to 400 year Temple administration is changed in south canara region from Aboriginals to Jains and different sects of brahmins and now everyone peacefully coexist.

Answer (score 1):

In the book  Sri Krishna Temple At Udupi  by B.N. Hebbar  available for free download here: https://archive.org/details/SriKrsnaTempleAtUdupi/page/n55/mode/2up?q=kukke

the author says, I quote:

// Page n55

During the course of Madhva’s tours within Tujunad in these two decades, he once journeyed to the Kukke-Subrahmanya-ksetra, the second holiest spot in the ParaSurama-ksetra, located on the banks of the Kumaradhara river in the Sulya taluk of Tujuva. Here, he is said to have encountered one Narasimha Tlrtha, the abbot of a Smarta-Bhagavata sampradaya institution, who challenged the acarya to a verbal duel. Madhva is said to have worsted this Bhagavata sampradaya abbot and won the latter’s institution as a booty for emerging victorious in the dialectical encounter. Madhva is then said to have converted that institution into an apostolic center of his own sect which goes by the name Kukke-Subrahmanya Matha today.71 The background and details of this episode (i.e., Madhva’s visit to Kukke-Subrahmanya) are given in Appendix I of this thesis, while narrating the foundation of the Kukke Subrahmanya Matha.//  Unquote.

From this one can see that the original character of that Temple was converted by Madhva upon the above episode. Madhva is said to have installed a Saligrama there, thereby making the conversion of the Shaiva/Smarta temple to a Vaishnava sectarian one.

This Saligrama installing there is stated by Wilson too in his 'A sketch of Religious  Sects of the Hindus' p. 93:

Quote //It seems not improbable, that the founder of the Mddhwa sect was,originally, a Saiva priest, and, although he became a convert to the Vaishnava faith, he encouraged an attempt to form a kind of compromise or alliance between the Saivas and Vaishnavas. Ma'dhwa was first initiated into the faith of Siva, at Ananteswar, the shrine of a Linga, and one of his names, Ananda Tirt'ha, indicates his belonging to the class of Dasnami Gosains, who were instituted by Sankara'cha'rya ; one of his first acts was to establish a Sdldgram, a type of Vishnu, at the shrine of Subrahmanya, the warrior son of Siva,//  unquote.